# getting a blob in python: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_blob'

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage

```py
blob = bucket.get_blob(f'Images/{id}.png')
```

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_blob'

getting the above error in face recognition project in python not able to overcome it

tried making changes in the code but the use of the blob is necessary since i am using storage bucket and I expect this error to be solved and not changing the code because i want it to be used using firebase.

Comment: Please show how you're defining `bucket`.

Comment: bucket = storage.bucket       i have already mentioned it after importing the libraries

Comment: Yes, well, you will need to call that function. `bucket = storage.bucket('your_bucket_name_here')`.